# Can't view variables within a static method

Tags: python, python-3.x

EDIT:
Ok so here is the background. I am trying to understand code written by a coworker. He has specifically written the code in the format of this example:

```
>>> class A:
        @staticmethod
        def ok(abc):
            thebigone=abc
```

(This is a simplification but the style is the same. Namely, a variable was declared in a `@staticmethod` within a class)

So since I am new to his code, I wanted to see what type of data `thebigone` was.I called the function in the shell and tried to use the to return the contents of this variable. I ran the function `ok` and then tried to use the shell to print the contents of the variable `thebigone` but the shell returned a definition error.

Here are the commands I tried in the shell:

```
>>> class A:
        @staticmethod
        def ok(abc):
            thebigone=abc


>>> A.ok('d')
>>> thebigone
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    thebigone
NameError: name 'thebigone' is not defined
>>> A.thebigone
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    A.thebigone
AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'thebigone'
```

After running the function, is it possible for the shell to return the contents of the variable, `thebigone` without altering the code? If not why is that?

Thanks

Comment: as it is assigned, `THEBIGONE` is a variable in the local namespace of the method. Try with `a.THEBIGONE = ...`

Comment: @Pynchia I fixed the indentation. Whoops. Ok so I didn't give enough context for this questions. One moment.

Comment: what you are trying to do doesn't make sense no matter whether you are adding a static method or not. This is just a local variable, so it will 'disappear' when any function returns (it could be just an instance method, for example)

Comment: OK. The question has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create global variables spontaneously inside a method any more than you can create them spontaneously inside a function. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to have *local* variables in a static method without polluting the global namespace.

In addition to Pynchia's solution, you can declare a global variable outside the class, and reference it explicitly with `global`:

```
THEBIGONE = None
class a:
    @staticmethod
    def ok(abc):
        global THEBIGONE
        THEBIGONE = abc
```

Or you might want to use a classmethod to make it a member of the class:

```
class a:
    @classmethod
    def ok(cls, abc):
        cls.THEBIGONE = abc
```

Class methods are generally more useful than static methods, so consider whether that might be a better solution to your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

as it is assigned, `THEBIGONE` is a variable (name) in the local namespace of the method, not of the class.

Try with

```
a.THEBIGONE = ...
```

Generally speaking, in Python `where` the assignment takes places defines the namespace where the name ends up.

So the assignment `THEBIGONE = ...` makes it go in the current namespace, i.e. the method's.

Unless, you explicitly specify where the name should go, e.g.

- an object (usually called `self` in instance methods) with `self.THEBIGONE = ...`
- a class, with `a.THEBIGONE = ...` in your case. Note that, as suggested in trentcl's answer, you could make the method a `classmethod` and avoid using the class' name explicitly.
- etc.

BTW: class names should start with capital letters, using the CapWords convention, leave lowercase to variables.

Please see the guidelines described in Python's [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I am new to programming and since I was messing around in my shell I didn't think much about readability. Thank you for referring me to a guidelines page I will edit the question to match the standards.